# yard-rspec-plugin and support for modules

Tags: ruby, rspec, yard

I am trying to get the yard-rpec-plugin to work.
For the given example it works, but when I add a module (as my code has), it does not give the rspec info in the doc.

To give an example, the following does not work, but leave out the 'Module Test' and it works.

```
module Test
  class String
    # Pig latin of a String
    def pig_latin
      self[1..-1] + self[0] + "ay"
    end
  end
end
```

While going through the code I noticed that in the RSpecItHandler, the following returns a Proxy when using modules. It seems part of the problem.

```
obj = P(owner[:spec])
```

Apparently the owner (the describe handler) is not yet in the namespace?

PS. The documentation for yard is actually quite good (and I read it), but I cannot find information about this specific part.

If feel sympathy for Thermatix's question, but it is closed as unclear ([Yardoc Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825960/yardoc-handlers/33826563#33826563)). Therefore I ask this more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code base and found that the following works

Instead of

```
P(owner[:spec])
```

Use

```
P(namespace, owner[:spec])
```

That takes care of the name-spacing of modules...